# ACS Management Service

Tags: azure, acs

I have created (by hand) a topic called 'testtopic' at the root level. I am trying to obtain a SWT programmatically from the 
ACS Management Service, then use that SWT in an effort to send a message to the 'testtopic' topic. To retrieve the SWT, I use
the following code:

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.BaseAddress = string.Format("https://connectedcloudapps.accesscontrol.windows.net");

    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
    {"wrap_name", "publisher"},
    {"wrap_password", "password"},
    {"wrap_scope", "https://connectedcloudapps.servicebus.windows.net/testtopic/"}
    };

    // WebClient takes care of the URL Encoding
    byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadValues("WRAPv0.9", "POST", values);

    string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
    var token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(response
    .Split('&')
    .Single(value => value.StartsWith("wrap_access_token=",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Split('=')[1]);
```

THE ABOVE WORKS FINE, AS I RECEIVE A SWT IN RETURN. SO FAR SO GOOD...I THINK

What follows is the configuration for the service identity, rules, etc:

```
Service identity
Name: publisher
Type:Password
Effective Date: 4/5/2013
Expiration Date: 4/5/2014

Rule group:
Name: publisherrule
Used by the following relying party applications:publisher rp
Rules (net.windows.servicebus.action):
IF
Input claim issuer: Access Control Service
Input claim type: nameidentifier
Input claim value: publisher
THEN
Output claim type:net.windows.servicebus.action
Output claim value:Send

Relying Party Applications
Name: publisher rp
realm:https://connectedcloudapps.servicebus.windows.net/testtopic
Return URL: <empty>
Error URL: <empty>
Token format: SWT
Token lifetime (secs):600
Authentication Settings
Identity providers:
<No Identity providers selected>

Rule groups:
Select the rule groups to use for this relying party application when processing claims.
'pubishrule' is selected via checkbox
Token Signing Keys:
Service Namespace Symmetric Key
```

Once everything is configured, I use the following, which I have changed many, many times, but cannot get it to send to the topic:

```
var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSimpleWebTokenProvider(token); //token is what was retrieved in above code
var factory = MessagingFactory.Create(ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "connectedcloudapps", string.Empty), tokenProvider);
var sender = factory.CreateTopicClient("testtopic");
var msg = new BrokeredMessage("Yahoooooooo");
try
{
    sender.Send(msg);
}
```

The error i am receiving is:

> {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The token provider was unable to
>   provide a security token while accessing
>   'https://connectedcloudapps-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'.
>   Token provider returned message:
>   'Error:Code:401:SubCode:T2002:Detail:Audience not
>   valid.:TraceID:bcd601fc-ac1b-4c23-bd85-67d8aeda83df:TimeStamp:2013-04-07
>   17:13:58Z'. ---> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException:
>   The token provider was unable to provide a security token while
>   accessing
>   'https://connectedcloudapps-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'.
>   Token provider returned message:
>   'Error:Code:401:SubCode:T2002:Detail:Audience not
>   valid.:TraceID:bcd601fc-ac1b-4c23-bd85-67d8aeda83df:TimeStamp:2013-04-07
>   17:13:58Z'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned
>   an error: (401) Unauthorized.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.GetAccessTokenCore(Uri
>   requestUri, String appliesTo, String requestToken, String
>   simpleAuthAssertionFormat, TimeSpan timeout, String& expiresIn)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.ThrowException(Uri
>   requestUri, WebException exception)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.GetAccessTokenCore(Uri
>   requestUri, String appliesTo, String requestToken, String
>   simpleAuthAssertionFormat, TimeSpan timeout, String& expiresIn)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderHelper.GetAccessTokenByAssertion(Uri
>   requestUri, String appliesTo, String requestToken, String
>   simpleAuthAssertionFormat, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.SimpleWebTokenProvider.OnBeginGetToken(String
>   appliesTo, String action, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProvider.GetTokenAsyncResult..ctor(TokenProvider
>   tokenProvider, String appliesTo, String action, Boolean bypassCache,
>   TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProvider.BeginGetToken(String appliesTo,
>   String action, Boolean bypassCache, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderUtility.GetMessagingToken(ITokenProvider
>   tokenProvider, Uri baseAddress, String appliesTo, String action,
>   Boolean bypassCache, TimeSpan timeout)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenProviderUtility.GetMessagingToken(ITokenProvider
>   tokenProvider, Uri baseAddress, String appliesTo, String action,
>   Boolean bypassCache, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageCreator.GetAuthorizationToken(String
>   appliesTo, String action)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageCreator.GetAuthorizationHeader(String
>   action)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageCreator.CreateWcfMessageInternal(String
>   action, Object body, Boolean includeToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageCreator.CreateWcfMessage(String
>   action, Object body)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.GetOverheadSize()
>   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender..ctor(String
>   path, SbmpMessagingFactory messagingFactory, SbmpMessageCreator
>   messageCreator, LinkInfo linkInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.CreateSenderLinkSettings..ctor(SbmpMessagingFactory
>   messagingFactory, String entityName, Nullable`1 entityType, String
>   transferDestinationEntityName)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.CreateSenderLinkSettings..ctor(SbmpMessagingFactory
>   messagingFactory, String entityName, Nullable`1 entityType)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpTopicClient.OnBeginCreateSender(TimeSpan
>   timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(AsyncCallback
>   c, Object s)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OpenOnceManagerAsyncResult`1.BeginOperation()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OpenOnceManagerAsyncResult`1.OpenComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OpenOnceManagerAsyncResult`1..ctor(OpenOnceManager
>   openOnceManager, TimeSpan openTimeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state, Func`3 beginOperation, EndOperation`1 endOperation)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.Begin[T](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Func`3 beginOperation, Func`2 endOperation)
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient.BeginCreateSender(TimeSpan
>   timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient.EnsureCreateInternalSender()
>   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient.ThrowIfSenderNull(String
>   operationName)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient.Send(BrokeredMessage
>   message)    at Console.Program.PostToTopic(Uri uri, String token) in
>   c:\Poc City\AirConCloud\Console\Program.cs:line 56}

At the end of the day, I will have many, many service identities, each of which will need access to the topic, either with different access rights.

1. Is the above approach correct and I am only missing minor plumbing
   details?
2. This will not work and needs a redesign?

If 1, what is wrong and if 2, how should this be done.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried changing the realm to be the root of the topic?  e.g. set `wrap_scope` to https://connectedcloudapps.servicebus.windows.net/

Comment: Also, reference code seems to do this to get the token: `var token = Uri.UnescapeDataString(responseString.Split('&')[0].Split('=')[1]);`.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: (back to my first comment) You seem to be creating the topic *after* you create the management credentials.  That doesn't sound safe to me.

Comment: Hi Peter, the wrap_scope mod returns no token whatsoever and the Uri mod still gives a 401. I have created the topic by hand in the management page, first creating the topic, then the service identity. I certainly appreciate the ideas, though